# POSIX to DOS and DOS to POSIX path conversion in C

Tags: c, gcc, cygwin, posix, dos

I was playing with the Cygwin GCC, where I wanted to print the current directory path using glib's `g_get_current_dir` in Windows and as well as in Linux. The problem is that the app is printing the path always in posix format in windows. But I wanted it to print in dos format in windows and posix format in linux. How would I do that? I know about cygpath utility but that is an external utility, I am looking for a standard library functions or something similar to do that from within **C** code.

Can someone please help me?

NOTE: I know it's a very basic question, but could not find anything particular about it in SO, so if it is a duplicate question, please point me to the right thread, I'll delete this one happily.

Comment: Did you thing about checking how `cygpath` does it? There's probably a cygwin API that does (most of) the work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that with the `cygwin_conv_path` function, documented in the [Cygwin API Reference](http://cygwin.com/cygwin-api/func-cygwin-conv-path.html).

Comment: Actually I did it already by looking into cygpath source code as Mat suggested. I'll post the code here also. Thanks for the pointing to the right location anyway. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I have came up with looking into cygpath source code (which was in C++, so modified it a bit according to my need)

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <windef.h>
#include <sys/cygwin.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <glib-2.0/glib.h>

int conv_dos_path(char *filename, int absolute_flag, char *converted_path) {

    char *buf = NULL, *tmp;
    wchar_t *buf2 = NULL;
    DWORD len = 32768;
    ssize_t err;
    int print_tmp = 0;
    cygwin_conv_path_t conv_func = CCP_POSIX_TO_WIN_W
            | (absolute_flag ? CCP_ABSOLUTE : CCP_RELATIVE);

    if (!filename || !filename[0]) {
        puts("Can't convert empty path");
        return 0;
    }

    buf = (char *) g_try_malloc(len);
    buf2 = (wchar_t *) g_try_malloc(len * sizeof(wchar_t));
    if (buf == NULL) {
        puts("Out of memory error.");
        return 0;
    }

    err = cygwin_conv_path(conv_func, filename, (void *) buf2, len);
    if (err) {
        puts("Error while converting path.");
        return 0;
    }
    wcstombs(buf, buf2, 32768);
    tmp = buf;
    if (strncmp(buf, "\\\\?\\", 4) == 0) {
        len = 0;
        if (buf[5] == ':')
            len = 4;
        else if (!strncmp(buf + 4, "UNC\\", 4))
            len = 6;
        if (len && strlen(buf) < PATH_MAX + len) {
            tmp += len;
            if (len == 6)
                *tmp = '\\';
            print_tmp = 1;
        }
    }

    converted_path = memcpy(converted_path, tmp, strlen(tmp) + 1);
    if (buf2)
        g_free(buf2);
    if (buf)
        g_free(buf);

    return 1;
}

char* get_real_path(char* filename){
    char actualpath[PATH_MAX + 1];
    char *ptr, *real_path;

    ptr = realpath(filename, actualpath);
    if(ptr == NULL){
        char buf[256];
        strerror_r(errno, buf, 256);
        puts(buf);
        return NULL;
    }
    real_path = (char*)g_malloc(strlen(ptr));
    conv_dos_path(ptr, 1, real_path);
    return real_path;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    g_setenv("CYGWIN", "nodosfilewarning", 1);
    char* path = get_real_path(argv[1]);
    if(path)
        puts(path);
    g_free(path);
    return 0;
}
```